# List view with Dynamic Row Item Android

Tags: android, gridview, android-custom-view, custom-lists

I have to display `listview` with dynamic row item.
In first row I have to set one child.
In second row I have to set two childs.

So in this sequence, I have to set row item.

I want this kind of example.

Please find attached image for reference.

[image]

I have to set dynamic row based on child set in this way.

If row has two childs I have to set two data in that row from arraylist.

Suppose I have 10 records, only 7 row should set in list as per design.

If any reference link available, let me know.

Comment: try to use getViewType() base adapter check : http://learnncode.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/listview-getviewtype-and-getviewtypecount-in-action/

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom adapter(a class that extends `BaseAdapter`) and then in `getView()` method of your adapter

```
if(position%2==0){
    //code for showing row with one child
}
else{
    //code for showing row with two children
}
```

Comment: @Harry,Toggling a view between VIEW.GONE and VIEW.VISIBLE can be a very expensive task inside the getview(..) which will sure affect the list scroll. This can be easily managed and tackled with listview’s pre-defined methods getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType(..)

Comment: @HareshChhelana I think it is the case, when user totally needs to inflate a different layout based on positions, rather then just making view visible or gone.

Comment: No, we don't change any visibility here. There are 2 kinds of view resource (.xml) that you need to make, let's call it **list_item1.xml** (one child) and **list_item2.xml** (two children).

If `position%2==0` then `rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item1, null)`. Else, `rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item2, null)`. That's it.

Comment: @Harry,so you inflate view every time base position ?

Comment: There must be a view inflated in `getView` of an Adapter, isn't it? So yeah, I just will just do that.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Displaying such a data is to inflate one row and depending on the condition you may hide or make a view visible but it is very expensive task inside the getview(..) which will sure affect the list scroll. This can be easily managed and tackled with listview’s pre-defined methods :

1) [getViewTypeCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int))

2) [getItemViewType()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount())

**Example Ref :** http://learnncode.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/listview-getviewtype-and-getviewtypecount-in-action/